# Coercing a db value into specific type using Scan

Tags: go

I'm trying to read a UUID retrieved from Postgres, using github.com/jackc/pgx, into a variable of type uuid.UUID (From the github.com/google/uuid package).

An example code could be:

```
var dbId = uuid.UUID 
err = db.Pool.QueryRow("SELECT id FROM users WHERE objectname = $1;", objectUUID.String()).Scan(&dbId)
  if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to fetch from database: %v", err)
    return
  }
```

The quickfix is to store the dbId in a temporary variable and then later convert said temporary variable into the correct type, but I have a feeling that there is a better, or more idiomatic, way to do it.

The error I'm getting is:

```
2018/02/12 07:09:18 handlers.go:187: Failed to fetch from database: can't scan into dest[1]: cannot assign &{[127 122 68 237 130 120 65 78 159 189 9 188 27 48 117 88] 2} into *uuid.UUID
```

Comment: How is the (UU)ID field defined in database (ie it's data type)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors says that you are trying to Scan a struct pointer to the UUID pointer. The struct is defined [here](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/pgtype/uuid.go#L11). So basically you should use this struct and Scan it into that and then convert the byte array in the struct to whatever UUID type you are using.

Comment: That’s what I ended up doing as a quick fix - Reading it into a [16]byte and converting it to uuid.UUID. Is that the cleanest way to do it, bar patching the DB library (pgx)?